# Declaring variable in different class not working as3

Tags: actionscript-3, var

I have a public var called monster number in my monster class.

```
public var monsterNumber:int;
```

And in my document class, I want to give monsterNumber a number, lets say 5.

It's still tracing monsterNumber as 0 in my monster class, but 5 in my document class. Is there any way to change this var in my document class?

Comment: Do you have an instance of your monster class in your document class ?

Comment: Yes. this line of code public var grunt:Monster = new Monster(); is in my document class. And the monsterNumber is a public var in the Monster class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can create a instance of Monster and modify it's property monsterNumber  :

```
// in your document class

var monster:Monster = new Monster();
monster.monsterNumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your variable as a static variable so you can change its value from anywhere you want.